# Rails migration: is it ok to use 'nil' as the default value for a boolean field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Is there anything wrong with defaulting a boolean field to `nil` rather than `false` with an ActiveRecord migration for use with Postgres?

I like how it gives a small bit of extra data- whether or not that field has been marked as true or false yet.

Comment: Depends if your field actually has three states (true, false, unknown) or just two (true, false).

Comment: I don't actually depend on the third "unknown" state, just an interesting piece of data I can check up on. The way I check boolean vals isn't thrown off by the use of nil.

Comment: Don't do it if you don't need it. My policy is to make everything NOT NULL unless I have a good reason for allowing NULLs, things go easier that way.

Comment: sounds like sound advice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is nothing to stop you from using nil on boolean - but I personally like my booleans to be true or false, i've found that having nil can lead to some ugly code

Comment: Ugly code indeed. If you need the third, `nil` / `unknown`, value then you really should be using an enum or a state machine I think. Otherwise, you're just fighting things and the onus is on you to ensure you're checking for the `nil` value **everywhere**.